# Trying to get CPU ID

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the CPU ID from the machine.

I found the following code somewhere:

```
System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'ManagementClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

**EDIT**

At the top of my document I have:

```
using System.Management;
```

Comment: `(are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Is there a `System.Management` DLL in your References project folder? If not, you need to right click on the folder and add that reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the assembly `System.Management.dll` (`System.Management` namespace) to your project.

Also make sure you are not using the .NET 4 client profile as target framework, if so switch to ".NET framework 4".

Comment: @PeeHa, with all due respect, and reading between the lines, I don't believe you actually have. Your `using System.Management` statement is **not** the same thing as adding a reference. See Evan's comment to your question.

Comment: @PeeHaa: It's not enough to add a `using` statement, you have to add a reference to the assembly. For that right-click "References" in your project and select "Add reference" - then pick `System.Management`

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a reference to the `System.Management` assembly?

Comment: I don't understand what your comment means. If it mean "I've already done that", please update your question to specify. Otherwise, please clarify.